# Get JSON from Trello in my own domain to create a table in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, jsonp, trello

I am trying to load the JSON data from Trello in my domain kizzton.com but it does work.
I am able to get it in my domain if I download the JSON file from Trello and I upload it to my domain, with the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $.getJSON( "http://kizzton.com/ovktypEd.json", function(data) {
                $.each(data.cards, function(i, f) {
                    var tblRow = "<tr class=\"content\">" + "<td>" + f.name + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.id + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.idList + "</td>" + "<td> " + f.idMembers + "</td>" + "</tr>"
                    $(tblRow).appendTo("#entrydata tbody");
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id= "entrydata">
            <thead>
                <th>Numero de pedido</th>
                <th>Fecha de pedido</th>
                <th>Estado</th>
                <th>Diseñador</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have been already few weeks trying to load from Trello (https://trello.com/b/ovktypEd.json) or from my other domain ratonero.es (http://ratonero.es/ovktypEd.json) with the following JSONP code but it does not work:

```
$.getJSON( "http://ratonero.es/ovktypEd.json?callback=?", function(data) {...
```

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Sorry to ask you that, but how should I accept it?

Comment: sorry either, i deleted my comment because i'm not so sure if it was correct.
I also don't have the answer to your follow up question.
For traceability: i said the server is probably not accepting cross origin request